# angularjs optimizing counting only once

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

I have to show a count in a bunch of places.

```
.container(ng-controller="counting")
  small {{count()}} 
    ng-pluralize(count='count()', when='{0: "Nothing", 1: "voter", 2: "multiple"}')
  small {{count()}} 
    ng-pluralize(count='count()', when='{0: "Nothing", 1: "voter", 2: "multiple"}')
  small {{count()}} 
    ng-pluralize(count='count()', when='{0: "Nothing", 1: "voter", 2: "multiple"}')
```

In this example there's 6 counts repeated. the count function is runned 6 times and is pretty heavy with filtering and other operations. Is there a way I can run count only once but still have the counts update when the "counting" scope changes? I know I can $watch in code manually but maybe there's an easier way in angular?

Comment: You should take a look at [Lodash's memoize function](http://lodash.com/docs#memoize) :)

Comment: @Julien if you could write an answer about how to use it that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to achieve this:

1) **By caching inside the template:**
you can do an assignment to a variable inside an expression

```
{{countCache = count()}},
```

then reference it later inside the template:

```
{{countCache}}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tzK7icQArAwPnZtxQznq?p=preview)

**Edit**:
**2) caching inside Count function (variable Memoization):**
Another more general approach is to add caching to the count function :

```
function count(){
  var result = 0;
  if(!count.cache || //parameters have been changed){ 
     // calculate result
     count.cache = result;  
  }
  return count.cache;
}
```

**3) using `$scope.$watch`:**

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
 if(//parameters have changed){
   return true;
 }else {
   return false
 }
},function(){
   //calculate new count
   $scope.count = result;
});
$scope.count = 0;
```

and reference `count` variable from inside template.

Comment: Better to do this in the underlying controller, the view shouldn't contain any logic.

Comment: @simoned then you're writing a watcher?

Comment: @simoned, it depends on the use case, if the controller (where count is defined) is tied to only one template, it's convenient to cache inside the template itself(this is not really logic).
still, I edited my answer to add a more general approach.

Comment: Thanks, like I said in the question doing a watch in the controller is fairly straightforward, but I was looking for an easier pattern. I think I'm going with the caching in the template expression as I think @simoned belief that the view shouldn't contain logic is super wrong.

Comment: @Harry that's the whole point of having a Model-View-Controller approach. The only logic contained in views should be conditional logic to render the view. In this case you are actually implementing some kind of caching, so IMHO it's something more than that. But you can obviously take the approach you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [memoize function of Lodash.](http://lodash.com/docs#memoize)

**How to do it ?**

0) Download lodash and load the script in your `index.html`

1) In your controller, add a dependency to `$window` and modify the definition of your count() function from

```
$scope.count = function() {
// Do awesome things 
}
```

to

```
$scope.count = $window._.memoize(function() {
// Do awesome things 
});
```

If your count method can return differents values over times, you will have to clear the cache

3) Either use `$scope.count.cache = {}` to clear the value when it's needed or you can give your own resolver function to create a cache key and thus not lose your result.
For example, if your count function use `$scope.someVar` which is a String to compute its result, you can use the following resolver :

```
function() {
return $scope.someVar;
}
```

and declare `$scope.count` as:

```
$scope.count = $window._.memoize(function() {
// Do awesome things 
},
function() {
return $scope.someVar;
}
);
```

**How does it works ?**

At each call, of a memoized function, the resolver will look in the cache if the result is stored or not (by default, the resolver returns the first argument converted to a string which had some gibberish appended).
If a result was found, it's returned.
Else, the function is computed and the return stored in the cache.

**Good practice**

Create a factory to return the _:

```
angular.module('myLittleApp')
.factory('LodashFactory', ['$window', function($window) {
    return $window._;
  }]);
```

Comment: Also worth noting that memoized functions that take no arguments return the same value every time `var foo = _.memoize(function() { return new Date().getMilliseconds() })` creates a cache like `{ 1413031900271undefined=867}` on the first execution and then `foo()` returns 867 every time.